# Way to select all columns from table and near each one the same column name with prefix?

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have a table with the following columns:

```
"col1", "col2", "col3", "new_col1", "new_col2", "new_col3" ...
```

I want to display the columns in the following way:

```
select col1, new_col1, col2, new_col2, col3, new_col3 ...
```

Is there a **select command/keyboard shortcut** that I can do that without copy each column in the select command

Thank you

Comment: No, there is not. If you have such a problem then your table design is most probably wrong

Comment: Order to display fields in the Select query its not an incorrect design, it is equivalent to a request to display the first name column next to the Last Name column

Comment: Why can't you just type the query? Should take less time than asking a question.

Comment: Bill Gates once said he prefers lazy developers because they find easy ways to complicated problems :)
I have several tables each has a large number of columns, for each one I need to generate such a query so that I can easily see the original value in the column compared to the new value in the column with the prefix, if there is no choice then I will do it manually

Comment: `SELECT` the column names from information schema and order them by `replace(name, 'new_', ''), case when name like 'new[_]%' then 1 end`. Copy past the results in your favorite editor and do some regex replace.

Answer (score 1):

I have a custom procedure mapped to `Ctrl+8` shortcut.

It's something like that:

```sql
CREATE or ALTER PROC dbo.utl_get_select(
  @table sysname,
  @alias varchar(10) = 'v'
)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  DECLARE @query varchar(max) = 'SELECT';

  SELECT @alias = ISNULL(@alias, 'v')

  SELECT @query = @query + ' ' + @alias + '.' + QUOTENAME(c.name)+','
  FROM sys.objects t 
  JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
  WHERE t.name = @table
  ORDER BY c.column_id ASC;

  SELECT @query = LEFT(@query, LEN(@query)-1) + ' ';
  SELECT @query + 'FROM dbo.' + @Table + ' ' + @alias;
END;
```

We could also use `STRING_AGG` in SQL Server 2017 or newer.

You can also compare columns names to achieve some customised order.

And the result for `EXEC dbo.utl_get_select 'users'`

```sql
SELECT v.[id], v.[login], v.[email], v.[name], v.[last_name] FROM dbo.users v
```

Comment: NO ONE should be routinely using NOLOCK hint without any reason. Nor should one be "recommending" its usage without noting the problems it can produce. It is highly unlikely such a hint is needed here - so [stop splattering your code with nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Removed NOLOCK-s, Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script for Insert and Select

```
DECLARE @String nvarchar(max)='',@Column nvarchar(100),@Insert nvarchar(max), @Select nvarchar(max),@TBL_NAME nvarchar(150)

SET @TBL_NAME = 'TestTable'

DECLARE CURS CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TBL_NAME

OPEN CURS
FETCH NEXT FROM CURS INTO @Column

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    SET @String = @String +'['+@Column+'],'+'['+@Column+'_NEW],'
    FETCH NEXT FROM CURS INTO @Column
END
CLOSE CURS
DEALLOCATE CURS

SET @String = SUBSTRING(@String,1,LEN(@String)-1)
SET @Insert = 'INSERT INTO ['+@TBL_NAME+'] ('+@String+')'
SET @Select = 'SELECT '+@String

Select @Insert,@Select
```